# MYSQL Error 1064 el sincronizar base de datos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

> Buenas, tengo una consulta, a la hora de ejecutar este código me sale el siguiente error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY (`Factura_idFactura`)
  REFERENCES `agro`.`Factura` (`idFactura`)...' at line 2
SQL Code:
        ALTER TABLE `agro`.`Detalle_factura`
          FOREIGN KEY (`Factura_idFactura`)
          REFERENCES `agro`.`Factura` (`idFactura`)
          ON DELETE NO ACTION
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          FOREIGN KEY (`Producto_idProducto`)
          REFERENCES `agro`.`Producto` (`idProducto`)
          ON DELETE NO ACTION
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION

SQL script execution finished: statements: 7 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

> Cuál podría ser el error en la sintaxis?? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que estás escribiendo en el  `ALTER TABLE` como si fuese en el  `CREATE TABLE`.

Ten en cuenta que aquí se trata de modificar la tabla, por tanto, **debes indicar a la sentencia `ALTER TABLE` el tipo de modificación que quieres hacer**. En este caso, como quieres agregar una restricción, debes usar `ADD CONSTRAINT`, pasando luego a definir la restricción. Observa que por cada restricción debes poner primero `ADD CONSTRAINT`.

```
    ALTER TABLE `agro`.`Detalle_factura`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Detalle_factura_Factura_idFactura`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Factura_idFactura`)
        REFERENCES `agro`.`Factura` (`idFactura`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Detalle_factura_Producto_idFactura`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Producto_idProducto`)
        REFERENCES `agro`.`Producto` (`idProducto`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Para más detalles consulta la sintaxis de `ALTER TABLE` en el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html).